# How to get user information from sharepoint site to my webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to developed a webpart that get all users information  with user images from sharepoint 2007 site.  Please suggest me how can achive this. Is there any webservices that can i use in my custome webpart? Please suggest solution for the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UserProfileService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/infopath/get-the-user-profile-through-moss-web-services) to get user details. Details about the same for [SharePoint 2010 is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms494053%28v=office.14%29).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. can you please tell me can we get user profile picture also using this service?